# Angular2 - Routing for file download not working

Tags: angular, download, angular2-routing

I have a set of files under following path:

**/assets/myFolder**

I have to make them downloadable from the application.

Now I'm trying to implement the download link like this :

```
<a href="/assets/myFolder/file.pdf" download>click here to download the file</a>
```

When I click on the link, I get the file but the content is the homepage html file.

I think that I have to customize something in the app.routing but I don't know how.

Comment: Please check properly as this should work. If possible take screenshot and update your question.

Comment: what  is the path of the html file. writing relative path may work "../../assets/myFolder"

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was not a real problem...
All works properly, I was just testing the download with a file that contains white spaces...
Those are not allowed in web...